# ISC DHCP/DDNS setup: Static entries for non-dhcp clients

Tags: bind, dhcp, bind9

I have set up a local network with ISC BIND9 and DHCP service. New leases trigger the DHCP to add an A and PTR record which works perfectly.

I also added lots of static host entries in the dhcpd.conf. Now I noticed that the DDNS update only works for clients that actually request a lease from the DHCP server. I have a few devices in the network that do not support DHCP. I still added static entries in the dhcp.conf. For those, no lease is requested and now no DNS-records are created. What options do I have to add those static entries in a way that DNS-records get created?

I would prefer to only use the dhcpd.conf if possible. Greatly appreciate any suggestions!

Comment: Apparently this has to be done manually by freezing the zone, adding the host and then thaw the zone again, as answered [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/1085913/isc-dhcp-ddns-setup-static-entries-for-non-dhcp-clients/1103678#1103678) by [Eric](https://serverfault.com/users/547277/eric-henriksson)